# Android Studio don’t see all device

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

a few days ago there was no problem when I used my device to run the application. but suddenly when I plug the usb into my device android studio displays no device and I try to replace another device but still not detected in android studio even though in the file explorer device is detected. I tried using the same device and same usb on another laptop and it was detected. I've tried several answers like install adb but it still didn't work

Comment: did you upgrade your android studio?

Comment: Please check: 
- Developer mode is on;

Comment: must check your mobile is on charging mode!

Comment: no @MustufaAnsari

Comment: done before @bask0xff

Answer (score 1):

Could you tap `adb devices`on your cmd and check if you see your plugged devices.

If not please check if u correctly check the developer options "Enable USB debugging" from your device.

Answer (score 1):

Please check:

- Developer mode is on;
- USB debugging: enable;
- Verify apps over USB is off;
- only charging this device via USB - is off;
- switch USB computer connection to PTP mode or to File Transfer mode;
- ensure that you are applyed fingerprinting keys in popup window after connection new device to your computer;
- your USB-cable is real Data-Cable (not only for charging);

Answer (score 1):

Your `ADB drivers` arent compatible with your device, you need to install `Universal ADB drivers` or else try `open google ADB drivers` (Some phone companies don't support google ADB drivers).